# How to install Bioconductor packages without root privileges?

Tags: linux, r

I need to use BiomaRt, preferrably the version in the 3.1 release. See: http://www.ensembl.info/blog/2015/06/01/biomart-or-how-to-access-the-ensembl-data-from-r/

I tried to follow the installation instruction in the aformentioned page to run the program in a Linux-based server. Also, I tried this one: http://www.bioconductor.org/install/#install-R, but, unless root permission is given, they won't work. I have loaded other packages using this approach https://linuxishbell.wordpress.com/2010/12/10/install-r-package-without-root-accesson-linux/, but they seem unfited for my case. What is the most recommendable thing to do? I have searched the internet, but little advice by Bioconductor team and user is provided in such case.

Comment: I have installed many bioconductor packages without root access on both Redhat and Ubuntu. I ssh into the server, run `R`, run command `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")`, run `biocLite("biomaRt")`. At some point you will be prompted with 'Would you like to use a personal library instead?', and a suggested location. Just type `y` to accept, and continue with installation.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to install R from the scratch to install packages without root privilege. Try this way:

```
module load R
```

(say this is the R on the cluster, so now it is on your path and you can enter it by typing R)

```
export R_LIBS_USER=$HOME/apps/R:$R_LIBS_USER
```

(you are still on the Linux commandline, not in R yet)

```
R
```

(now you enter R)

```
install.packages("packagename")
```

Well done, it will install the package to HOME/apps/R

```
library(packagename)
```

(Try it and see it worked)

Answer (score 1):

***Solution***

The easiest way to do this is to install R [from source](http://cran.rstudio.com):

```
$ wget http://cran.rstudio.com/src/base/R-3/R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ tar xvf R-3.1.1.tar.gz
$ cd R-3.1.1
$ ./configure --prefix=$HOME/R
$ make && make install
```

The second-to-last step is the critical one.  It configures R to be installed into a subdirectory of your own home directory.

To run it on Linux and similar systems, add `$HOME/R/bin` to your `PATH`. Then, commands like `R` and `Rscript` will work.

On OS X, the `bin` dir is buried in `$HOME/R/R.framework/Versions/Current/Resources` instead, due to the way OS X packaging works.

You can give `--prefix=$HOME` instead if you don't wish to have R and all its dependencies hidden in its own subdirectory. If you are on Linux and have `$HOME/bin` in your `PATH` already, doing so would avoid the need to edit the `PATH`. The downside is that it makes later uninstallation harder, since R would be intermingled among your other `$HOME` contents.

This general pattern applies to a large amount of Unix software you can install from source code. If the software has a `configure` script, it probably understands the `--prefix` option, and if not, there is usually some alternative with the same effect.

These features are common for a number of reasons. Your case — where you can't get `root` to install the software into a typical location so you install into `$HOME` instead — is actually one of the least common uses for this sort of feature. Here are some more common use cases:

- Circumstances may dictate a better location than the standard default (`/usr/local`) such as `/usr`, `/opt/$PKGNAME`, etc.
- Binary package building systems (RPM, DEB, PKG, Cygport...) typically build and install the package into a special staging directory, then pack that up in such a way that it expands into the desired installation location.

***Have a look at those links***

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149451/install-r-in-my-own-directory
http://onertipaday.blogspot.be/2008/04/r-installing-on-unixlinux-no-root.html

***Otherwise***

You could may be use a virtual appliance, to install the app virtually with virtual root access